# Data not transferred between 2 forms using php-echo

Tags: php, html, forms, pdo

I am working on making update functionality in an html form. I am sending data from one form to other through `echo` to be updated. But I am not able to populate other from catching the data send from 1st form.

The field id text box is blank.

Here is my code:

**Sent key from from 1:**

```
  <tr>
    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['field_id'] ?></td>
    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['description'] ?></td>
    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['corner_points'] ?></td>
    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['notes'] ?></td>
    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><a target="_blank" href="Edit/edit-field.php?field_id=<?php echo $row['field_id'];?>">Edit</a></td>
  </tr>
```

**to receive data edit-field.php:**

```
<?php

    if(isset($GET["field_id"]))    
      {
       $field_id = $GET["field_id"]; 
      }

     try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT field_id, description, corner_points, notes FROM fields where field_id = $field_id");
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        ?>

   <form action="" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <h6> Field </h6>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">Field ID</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="field_id" id="field_id" value="<?php echo $result["field_id"];?>">
      </div>
   </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="submit1" type="submit">Update Records</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wouldn't you have to do a loop to fetch results? just like this example :

```
    <?php
// $pdo est un objet PDO
try{
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    exit('<b>Catched exception at line '. $e->getLine() .' (code : '. $e->getCode() .') :</b> '. $e->getMessage());
}
foreach($rows as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In edit-field.php the variable for parameters passed via the URL is $_GET not $GET.

Change the start of that file to:

```
if(isset($_GET["field_id"])) {
   $field_id = $_GET["field_id"]; 
}
```